# With facelets what is the equivalent to fmt:formatDate?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, facelets

I am converting a JSP web page to facelets view handler.

What is the equivalent to fmt:formatDate etc.?

I know that it isn't supported. But is there an alternative? A third level implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually in JSF, you would add a ([convertDateTime](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2_MR1/docs/tlddocs/f/convertDateTime.html)) converter to the control:

```
<h:outputText value="#{dateConverterBean.now}">
    <f:convertDateTime type="date" dateStyle="short" />
</h:outputText>
```

The [documentation for Facelets](https://facelets.dev.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html#taglib-available) implies they use the same.

Answer (score 1):

The f:convertDateTime converter uses GMT / UMT as the time zone for formatting the date/time.  This is pretty annoying, and can lead to the incorrect local date and time being displayed.  You can supply a time zone to the converter using a bean. I would suggest making your own converter.  Only takes a few lines of code and allows more exacting formatting.